# Build .net core webapi in openshift v3

Tags: asp.net-web-api, openshift, asp.net-core-1.1

I am very new to openshift and .net core .I try to build a web api project in .netcore 1.1 in openshift v3 .Any one have experience with it.A step-by-step guidance is very helpful for beginners . I created a ropo https://github.com/kuntal-b/netcoreWebAPI/ .

please help/share your experience .

Comment: You can find a series of blog posts about using dotNet with OpenShift at https://blog.openshift.com/category/technologies/dotnet/

Comment: all example demonstrate with 1.0 ,I want vs2017 .netcore 1.1 example .

Comment: The OpenShift S2I builder for dotNet has a version for 1.1. Have you tried that with same code structure?

Comment: I create a sample project in vs 2017 community and upload this .

Comment: Did you read all the dotNet blog posts on the OpenShift blog site. It provides an example of what you would do. In one of the posts it says that if you happened to be using 1.1, that can select that version when doing the deployment. I don't personally know about dotNet applications so can only point to those blog posts.

Comment: The example based on 1.0 but https://blog.openshift.com/asp-net-on-openshift-part-3-running-your-asp-net-code-on-openshift/  this post in point 6 only one line for 1.1 .no detailing.

Answer (score 0):

finally its working

Found a sample app https://github.com/redhat-developer/s2i-dotnetcore/tree/master/1.1/test/asp-net-hello-world

Take project.json from there (https://github.com/redhat-developer/s2i-dotnetcore/blob/master/1.1/test/asp-net-hello-world/project.json)

change version

```
"version": "1.1.0-*",
```

and remove (https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb/pull/14) because there was an error

> **Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1**

```
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" :"1.0.1" ,
```

**project.json** after modify

```
{
  "version": "1.1.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" :"2.0.0" ,
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore" :"1.1.2" ,
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" :"1.1.3" ,
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" :"1.0.3" ,
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" :"1.1.2" ,
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" :"1.1.1" ,
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" :"1.1.0" ,
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" :"1.1.2" ,
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" :"1.0.1" ,    
    "MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" :"7.0.7-m61" ,
    "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" :"1.1.2" ,
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.1.0",
          "type": "platform"
        },
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "hosting.json",
      "testCert.pfx"
    ]
  }
}
```

and build successful in open shift v3 with .net core 1.1

find sample app bellow link .
http://netcore-kuntal-test.7e14.starter-us-west-2.openshiftapps.com/api/values